# Transform a code type "If...Then...." to table using R?

Tags: r

Is there any way to transfrom the following SAS code:

```
    If CRM = 50 then coefgpc=coefgpc * 1;                       
    Else If CRM <= 54 then coefgpc=coefgpc * 1.12;                      
    Else If CRM <= 59 then coefgpc=coefgpc * 1.245;                     
    Else If CRM <= 99 then coefgpc=coefgpc * 1.609;                     
    Else If CRM = 100 then coefgpc=coefgpc * 1.987;                     
    Else If CRM >= 101 then coefgpc=coefgpc * 2.223;
```

into the table like this:

[image]

The 375 comes from the another file, it is supposed to be entered manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works.

```
txt <- " If CRM = 50 then coefgpc=coefgpc * 1;                       
      Else If CRM <= 54 then coefgpc=coefgpc * 1.12;                      
      Else If CRM <= 59 then coefgpc=coefgpc * 1.245;                     
      Else If CRM <= 99 then coefgpc=coefgpc * 1.609;                     
      Else If CRM = 100 then coefgpc=coefgpc * 1.987;                     
      Else If CRM >= 101 then coefgpc=coefgpc * 2.223;"

#Split the string into workable blocks with regex
splt <- strsplit(txt, split = "\n|\\*|=")[[1]]

#Extract elements with numbers
nos <- splt[grepl("[0-9]", splt)]

#odd-numbered entries are your limits
lims <- as.integer(gsub("[^0-9]", "", nos[seq(1, length(nos), by = 2)]))
#even-numbered entries are your factors
facts <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", nos[seq(2, length(nos), by = 2)]))

#wrap up into a 'data.frame'
data.frame(lower = c(lims[1], lims[-length(lims)] + 1),
           upper = c(lims[-length(lims)], 375L),
           Factor = facts)
```

Comment: `|` separates three things by which we split the text: by new line characters (`\n`), by asterisks (`\\*`), and by equals signs (`=`)